# while loop not stopping when criteria is met

Tags: android, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to do a snowball calculation for debt - for those who don't know - you make minimum payments on all loans from month to month. Once one is paid off, you take that minimum payment and add it to the next one - so on and so forth. I have each of my debt amounts on do while loops, but my screen turns black and I believe it's on an infinite loop. I have 10 total of these, but here are a few just to show how it's working:

```
    int tempTimeTaken=0;
    double newPmt = payment1 + aAmt;

    while(amount1>0){
        amount1 = (amount1 * rate1) - newPmt;
        tempTimeTaken++;
    }

    newPmt = newPmt + payment2;
    for (int i=0;i<tempTimeTaken;i++)
    {
        if(amount2>0){
        amount2 = (amount2 * rate2) - payment2;
        }
    }
    do{
        if (amount2>0){
        amount2 = (amount2 * rate2) - newPmt;
        tempTimeTaken++;}
    }while(amount2>0);
```

Each of the variables not initialized here are retrieved from a sharedpreference earlier in the activity. Once received, it's parsed in to a double (assuming it's not null).

```
    try
    {
        amount2 = Double.parseDouble(debtAmount2);
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        amount2 = 0;
    }
```

I've also tried the loops as

```
while (amount>0){
//do stuff
}
```

and that didn't work either - same effect.

Any suggestions on how to get this not to loop forever?

all data types are double (except tempTimeTaken is int) - initial values vary - they are input in a different activity and carried to this one via sharedpref with a default of 0

Comment: add the data type and initial values for rate1 amount1 amount2 etc. Make the program complete so it will be easier to debug

Comment: see updated types above

Comment: This works if `rate` and `newPmt` have reasonable values. Can you provide the exact values you used? Also, you can try to log loop execution steps and then use `logcat` to examine them. At least you will be able to confirm that it loops indefinitely.

Comment: I'll try the steps - for rate I used anything from 1 - 3.5  for newPmt I used anything from 500-2500 (debtPayment of 500 + addPayment of 20 etc)

Comment: update to my prior comment - it won't let me debug either, gets stuck (theoretically) in those loops - I'm reformatting and will post if I have an answer - I'm still open and looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the format of while loop is

```
while(check condition against loop counter){
     //do your things
     increment/ decrement loop counter
}
```

in your loop

```
 while(amount1>0){
     amount1 = (amount1 * rate1) - newPmt;
     tempTimeTaken++;
 }
```

you are assigning new value to loop counter amount1 and increment a tempTimeTaken. Print the value of amount1 in this loop check whether it gets negative at some point of time eg.

```
while(amount1>0){
    amount1 = (amount1 * rate1) - newPmt;
    Log.d("loop","Value of amount1 :"+amount1);
    tempTimeTaken++;
}
```